# data is undefined between shared service with angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-services

**Routes**

```js
export const SchoolyearsRoutes: RouterConfig = [
  { path: '', terminal: true, redirectTo: '/schoolyears' },
  {
    path: 'schoolyears', component: SchoolyearsRootComponent, children: [
      { path: '', component: SchoolyearsListComponent },
      { path: 'edit/:id', component: SchoolyearsEditComponent },
      { path: 'create', component: SchoolyearsCreateComponent }
    ]
  }];
```

**Service**:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Schoolyear } from './schoolyear';


@Injectable()
export class SchoolyearsEditService {

    public schoolyear: Schoolyear;

    constructor() { }
}
```

**Parent component:**

```js
import { Component }            from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES }    from '@angular/router';
import { SchoolyearsEditService } from '../schoolyears-edit.service';

@Component({  template:`<router-outlet></router-outlet>`,  providers: [SchoolyearsEditService]})
export class SchoolyearsRootComponent { }
```

**Child component:**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterConfig, Router, ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
import { SchoolyearsEditService } from '../schoolyears-edit.service';
import { Schoolyear } from '../schoolyear';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-schoolyears-edit',
  templateUrl: 'schoolyears-edit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['schoolyears-edit.component.css'],
})
export class SchoolyearsEditComponent implements OnInit {
  schoolyear: Schoolyear;
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, private schoolyearsService: SchoolyearsEditService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.schoolyear = this.schoolyearsService.schoolyear;
  };
}
```

**HTML**:

```html
schoolyear Id:
<input [value]="schoolyear.id">

schoolyear name:    
<input [value]="schoolyear.name">

schoolyear start date:
<input [value]="schoolyear.startDate">

schoolyear end date:    
<input [value]="schoolyear.endDate">
```

schoolyear in the html is always undefined.

Why is the data not correctly shared?

I provide the service in the parent component and share it in the children component. It should work but does not!

Comment: I don't see your assigning values anywhere to public "schoolyear: Schoolyear" variable in your service. So it obviously should be undefined, isn't it ?

Comment: see my comment to Günter at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

It probably is shared correctly, but it is getting the schoolyear value too late, when the DOM is already rendering. You can mitigate this by using the elvis operator or so called safe navigation operator.

```html
schoolyear Id:
<input [value]="schoolyear?.id">

schoolyear name:    
<input [value]="schoolyear?.name">

schoolyear start date:
<input [value]="schoolyear?.startDate">

schoolyear end date:    
<input [value]="schoolyear?.endDate">
```

This way it will enter the values into the inputs as soon as the schoolyear variable gets filled.

Comment: still undefined, did not help :-/

Answer (score 1):

You are copying primitive values

```ts
  ngOnInit() {
    this.schoolyear = this.schoolyearsService.schoolyear;
  }
```

this doesn't create a connection between service and your component. This is a one-time action.

If the value was not yet set on the service when it is copied (code above) then it's not going to happen.

Using `Observable`, in this case perhaps `BehaviorSubject` which emits the last emitted event to new subscribers would be a better option.

See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html for more details.

Comment: I just wonder why it works for many people on SO not using BehaviorSubject.

Comment: I would need a concrete example. What often works is not to copy values from the service to the component, but instead bind to the value of the service directly like `{{shoolyearsService.schoolyear.id}}` (maybe adding `?` like shown by @rinukkusu). Using observables is the more elegant solution because it push-notifies Angular about changes which allows more optimizations for change detection. Using observables makes your code more difficult to understand if you are not used to them, so for a start I think this would be a good option.

Comment: I found the error. It`s a PICNIC :D The edit function in the SchoolyearsListComponent (not listed above...) never got called as I use a RouterLink directly in the html...now it works. But I found another error use case maybe you observable advice can help here: When I directly enter the url /schoolyears/edit/5 in the url my schoolyear data is undefined of course because in the edit function I set the selected schoolyear to the edit service. I guess there is no solution for this right? Just load the schoolyear again via id from backend...

Comment: I don't really understand the problem. Maybe it's just too late and I should better go to bed :o Some code that demonstrates the problem might help. You can edit your question and add it there. Code in comments is unreadable)

Comment: I make it a new question, tomorrow then now its bed time! Sleep well!